Objects parented in the Viewport are not visible
In a 3d firemonkey app I placed on the form a TViewport and a 3d cube. if connect the cube to the view port (parented under the viewport in the 'Structure'), the cube is not visible anymore.
my setup
the form at design time (observe that nothing is visible)
The cube is visible if it is NOT parented under the viewport!
However, this 8 years old tutorial from Embarcadero shows that the cube parented under the view port and it worked.
I guess something changed in FMX since then.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjflkb1GzaM

Please provide a [mre], including both .pas and .fmx files.

Also please do not use external links as they may break in the future.

@TomBrunberg done

Sorry, but not as I asked you: "including both .pas and .fmx files" means that you include them as text in your question. Never refer to code on some external site. Please visit the help for SO and read about how to ask.

As you have visited SO since I answered your question I assume that you have seen my answer. As you have not said anything against my answer, I believe my answer was spot on correct. Please visit following two pages in help section of this site: someone-answers and why-vote. Using your right to cast your vote on an answer, and marking it as a correct one will help keeping this site going.

Although you did not respond to my request for a minimal reproducible example, I'm pretty sure the following is the case.
The point to note here is that there are two different form types (with respect to 2D and 3D), the classes being TForm (2D) and TForm3D (3D).

If you use a TForm and want to show 3D content in it, you must use TViewPort3D for the 3D components.

If, on the other hand, you use a TForm3D, then support for 3D components is already built in the form, and you don't need (actually can't) use TViewPort3D as parent for the 3D components.


Your description that the cube is not visible if placed on the view port is exactly what happens when you use a TViewport3D with a TForm3D.
